# Right Outer Join Not Returning Expected Rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to return a .NET datatable for a forecasting interface using the following SQL Server query that joins two tables:

```
SELECT accounts.AccountID
,accounts.Account
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN forecast.omonth = 1
            THEN forecast.ns1
        ELSE 0
        END) / 1 Jan
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN forecast.omonth = 2
            THEN forecast.ns1
        ELSE 0
        END) / 1 Feb
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN forecast.omonth = 3
            THEN forecast.ns1
        ELSE 0
        END) / 1 Mar
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN forecast.omonth = 4
            THEN forecast.ns1
        ELSE 0
        END) / 1 Apr
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN forecast.omonth = 5
            THEN forecast.ns1
        ELSE 0
        END) / 1 May
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN forecast.omonth = 6
            THEN forecast.ns1
        ELSE 0
        END) / 1 Jun
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN forecast.omonth = 7
            THEN forecast.ns1
        ELSE 0
        END) / 1 Jul
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN forecast.omonth = 8
            THEN forecast.ns1
        ELSE 0
        END) / 1 Aug
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN forecast.omonth = 9
            THEN forecast.ns1
        ELSE 0
        END) / 1 Sep
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN forecast.omonth = 10
            THEN forecast.ns1
        ELSE 0
        END) / 1 Oct
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN forecast.omonth = 11
            THEN forecast.ns1
        ELSE 0
        END) / 1 Nov
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN forecast.omonth = 12
            THEN forecast.ns1
        ELSE 0
        END) / 1 Dec
FROM accountForecast forecast
RIGHT OUTER JOIN account_tree accounts ON forecast.AccountID = accounts.AccountID
WHERE forecast.oYear = 2014
AND accounts.AccountID in (35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 78, 79, 80, 81, 1, 82, 176)
GROUP BY accounts.AccountID
    ,accounts.Account
```

The accountForecast table is structured as follows:
[image]

This query should return a row for all Account IDs in the WHERE clause (35, 36, 37, etc.), even if a given account does not have an entry in the accountForecast table, in which case the query should return 0s.

My query is currently only returning one row containing the AccountID that's already inserted in the accountForecast table.  Am I joining incorrectly?  What should I change?

EDIT:  I removed the `forecast.oYear = 2014` WHERE clause and it seems to be working as expected.  However, it's important that this query is fed the year parameter, as the data depends on it.  Is there any way to return all of the Account rows while still specifying the year?

Comment: how is the account_tree table setup?  also, which version of sql?

Answer (score 2):

Your filter excludes values that are `NULL`:

```
WHERE forecast.oYear = 2014
```

Answer (score 1):

It is tough to understand where your data is actually stored, but I'm assuming that all of the accounts are stored in `account_tree`? If so, try reversing the `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses:

```
FROM account_tree accounts 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN accountForecast forecast ON forecast.AccountID = accounts.AccountID
WHERE forecast.oYear = 2014
AND accounts.AccountID in (35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 78, 79, 80, 81, 1, 82, 176)
GROUP BY accounts.AccountID
    ,accounts.Account
```